# Android AlertDialog with a common message for 3 buttons

Tags: java, android

Please help me with my code
I need to show an Android `AlertDialogBox` with a common message for 3 buttons, i.e Yes, No, And Cancel. As in this I have used simple `Android AlertDialog` with a message for individual 3 buttons, i.e. Yes, No and Cancel.
So I think there is need of function to be call.

The layout and Java part are given below

Layout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.talent.simpledialogbox.MainActivity">

        <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="/hello_world"
            android:id="@+id/textView" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Yes"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:id="@+id/Yes"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:id="@+id/Cancel"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="No"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
            android:id="@+id/No"/>        
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Java Part**

```
package com.talent.simpledialogbox;   
import android.os.Bundle;enter code here
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresPermission;
import android.view.Menu;
import android`enter code here`.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button Yes,No, Cancel;
    Object myObject = new Object();
    RequiresPermission.Read FunctionCalling;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Yes = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Yes);
        No = (Button)findViewById(R.id.No);
        Cancel= (Button)findViewById(R.id.Cancel);
        Yes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Confirm Delete...");
                builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want delete this?");
                builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // Write your code here to invoke NO event
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on NO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
            }
        });
                No.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                        builder.setTitle("Confirm No)...");
                        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want delete this?");
                        builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                        builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // Write your code here to invoke NO event
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on NO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                        builder.show();
                    }
                });
                        Cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                                builder.setTitle("Confirm Cancel...");
                                builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want delete this?");
                                builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                });
                                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        // Write your code here to invoke NO event
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });
                                // Showing Alert Message
                                builder.show();
                            }
                        });
                   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign `AlertDialog` object and assign it to the `buider.create()`

```
   package com.talent.simpledialogbox;
    import android.os.Bundle;enter code here
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.support.annotation.RequiresPermission;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android`enter code here`.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        Button Yes,No, Cancel;
        Object myObject = new Object();
        RequiresPermission.Read FunctionCalling;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Yes = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Yes);
            No = (Button)findViewById(R.id.No);
            Cancel= (Button)findViewById(R.id.Cancel);
            Yes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    builder.setTitle("Confirm Delete...");
                    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want delete this?");
                    builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                    builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // Write your code here to invoke NO event
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on NO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();
                }
            });

            No.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    builder.setTitle("Confirm No)...");
                    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want delete this?");
                    builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         }
                     });
                    builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                         // Write your code here to invoke NO event
                             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on NO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                             dialog.cancel();
                        }
                            });
                            AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                            alertDialog.show();
                        }
                    });

            Cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    builder.setTitle("Confirm Cancel...");
                    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want delete this?");
                    builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // Write your code here to invoke NO event
                             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                              dialog.cancel();
                        }
                            });
                            AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                            alertDialog.show();
                         }
                     });
              }
    }
```

Comment: No, its not working . I just need to get an "Alert" when I click on these three button using alertDialog.show();